# Is there any way to replace deprecated CustomEvent.initCustomEvent() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

deprecated CustomEvent.initCustomEvent() how can I replace for code improvement on my old code.

Answer (score 5):

[Googling “JS initCustomEvent deprecated”](https://google.com/search?q=JS+initCustomEvent+deprecated) will find several relevant results, including the relevant documentation.

The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent) is pretty clear:

> Rather than using the feature, instead use specific event constructors, like [`CustomEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent).
> The page on [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) gives more information about the way to use those.

The latter link includes a section titled [The old-fashioned way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#the_old-fashioned_way) which shows exactly how the older API was used, along with the modern API usage.

Note that [`initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) and many related methods are deprecated, just like `initCustomEvent`, but also `initMessageEvent`, `initUIEvent`, etc.
The documentation there says (sans the bold formatting and redundant links):

> Do not use this method anymore as it is deprecated.
>
> Instead use specific event constructors, like `Event()`.
> […]

The [See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent#see_also) section also links to:

> The constructor to use instead of this deprecated method: [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event). More specific constructors can be used too.

The only difference between `initEvent` and `initCustomEvent` is that the latter accepts an additional `detail` parameter.
They are otherwise identical in their usage.
[`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) instantiates a new Event object, but since their constructors can be used, nowadays it’s essentially obsolete.
`document.createEvent("CustomEvent")` creates a `CustomEvent`, and so does `document.createEvent("customevent")`: the string is case-insensitive, the full list of supported event interfaces is [specified by WHATWG](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createevent), and `document.createEvent("Event")` creates a generic `Event` object.

The documentation provides examples of how to use `initCustomEvent`.
You can compare this to the usage of the modern `CustomEvent` API.

Deprecated way of initializing a custom event:

```js
const event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");

event.initCustomEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, detail);
```

Use this instead:

```js
const event = new CustomEvent(type, { bubbles, cancelable, detail });
```

In either case, in order to listen for it and dispatch it, this code remains the same:

```js
eventTarget.addEventListener(type, eventListener);
eventTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In both examples,

- `event` will be a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent),
- `type` is some string representing the kind of the event, e.g. `switchLampOn` or `animalCall` or whatever,
- `detail` is some custom data associated with the event — can be anything —,
- `eventTarget` is some [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget),
- `eventListener` is some function or [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).

`canBubble` and `cancelable` are boolean arguments in the deprecated approach.
`bubbles` and `cancelable` are boolean properties of the [`CustomEventInit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#parameters) object in the modern approach.
The `CustomEventInit` object is the second argument of the `CustomEvent` constructor.

For more information on what “bubbling” — and “capturing” — mean, see [MDN: Event bubbling and capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and [Stack Overflow: What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/4642212).
For more information on what “cancelable” does, see [MDN: the `Event.prototype.cancelable` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable), [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

---

Brief history overview:

There was a time before DOM was specified, but old Internet Explorer and Netscape did their own thing with events.
The de-facto implementations from this era are informally referred to as “DOM Level 0”.

- DOM Level 1 was specified in 1998 – 2000, but deferred specifying an event model to future specs.
- DOM Level 2 introduced `initEvent` et al. in 2000.
- DOM Level 3, finished in 2004 introduced `CustomEvent`.
- DOM Level 4, the current work, made all `Event` interfaces constructable, rendering `createEvent` obsolete.